# Paginating union_all query in Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have 3 tables of which I am trying to do a UNION_ALL query. This is the query.

```
compares =
  Compare
  |> join(:left, [comp], u in assoc(comp, :user))
  |> join(:left, [comp], c in assoc(comp, :camera))
  |> select([comp, u, c], %{
    title: comp.name,
    exid: comp.exid,
    table: "compares",
    requested_by: u.email,
    status: comp.status,
    camera_id: c.exid,
    created_at: comp.inserted_at
  })

timelapses =
  Timelapse
  |> join(:left, [tl], u in assoc(tl, :user))
  |> join(:left, [tl], c in assoc(tl, :camera))
  |> select([tl, u, c], %{
    title: tl.title,
    exid: tl.exid,
    table: "timelapses",
    requested_by: u.email,
    status: tl.status,
    camera_id: c.exid,
    created_at: tl.inserted_at
  })

Archive
|> join(:left, [a], u in assoc(a, :user))
|> join(:left, [a], c in assoc(a, :camera))
|> select([a, u, c], %{
  title: a.title,
  exid: a.exid,
  table: "archives",
  requested_by: u.email,
  status: a.status,
  camera_id: c.exid,
  created_at: a.created_at
})
|> union_all(^compares)
|> union_all(^timelapses)
```

This gives me all the results but because of a lot of data, I want to paginate it,  I tried using `scrivener_ecto` but it failed with such an error

```
* (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) each UNION query must have the same number of columns 

    query: SELECT count('*') FROM "archives" AS a0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = a0."requested_by" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cameras" AS c2 ON c2."id" = a0."camera_id" UNION ALL (SELECT c0."name", c0."exid", 'compares', u1."email", c0."status", c2."exid", c0."inserted_at" FROM "compares" AS c0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = c0."requested_by" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cameras" AS c2 ON c2."id" = c0."camera_id") UNION ALL (SELECT t0."title", t0."exid", 'timelapses', u1."email", t0."status", c2."exid", t0."inserted_at" FROM "timelapses" AS t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = t0."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cameras" AS c2 ON c2."id" = t0."camera_id")
    (ecto_sql 3.6.1) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:749: Ecto.A
```

is there any possibility to apply pagination to the `union_all` query to have such data

```
%{
  from: 1,
  items: [],
  limit: 50,
  page: 1,
  to: 50,
  total: 3618
}
```

any help would be grateful, if you see anything in the query which is alarming or could be changed to something better then please do suggest as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this query:

> SELECT count('*') FROM "archives" AS a0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = a0."requested_by" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cameras" AS c2 ON c2."id" = a0."camera_id" UNION ALL (SELECT c0."name", c0."exid", 'compares', u1."email", c0."status", c2."exid", c0."inserted_at" FROM "compares" AS c0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = c0."requested_by" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cameras" AS c2 ON c2."id" = c0."camera_id") UNION ALL (SELECT t0."title", t0."exid", 'timelapses', u1."email", t0."status", c2."exid", t0."inserted_at" FROM "timelapses" AS t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u1 ON u1."id" = t0."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cameras" AS c2 ON c2."id" = t0."camera_id")

As you can see the first query is trying to fetch the count while the last two queries are trying to fetch the fields and there is a mismatch in the fields selected by the queries joined by `UNION ALL` clause. The query formed isn't correct.

If you're using `scrivener_ecto` library, issue certainly lies within that.

To put more light on this, most of the pagination libraries which give the flexibility of adding pagination with fewer code changes do so by knowing the exact count of rows getting fetched from database so as to figure out the `previous_page`, `next_page`, etc to be returned in the API.

I'm not aware of any elixir library which can handle this but this can be achieved by writing a custom query instead:

```
Archive
|> join(:left, [a], u in assoc(a, :user))
|> join(:left, [a], c in assoc(a, :camera))
|> select([a, u, c], %{
  title: a.title,
  exid: a.exid,
  table: "archives",
  requested_by: u.email,
  status: a.status,
  camera_id: c.exid,
  created_at: a.created_at
})
|> union_all(^compares)
|> union_all(^timelapses)
|> order_by(:created_at)
|> limit(50)
|> offset((page-1)*50)
```

You'll have to expect an extra parameter `page`.
You can write another query to fetch the count of all such records for the `total` parameter.

P.S.: I'd avoid returning the number of rows for `total` parameter unless that's certainly required. Supporting `count(*)` with so many joins and unions is gonna certainly land you in a lot of trouble with performance when the number of rows grows in the tables.